# How to change color of A specified cell(s) when checkbox is checked In Google Sheets?

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I need to change the color of certain cells, if next to them checkbox in `TRUE`.
I found this article, but it doesn’t say how to change the text (what value should be entered):

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7684717?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

In my case, I want these cells in green color

[image]

Answer (score 2):

custom formula for conditional formatting:

```
=IF($C1=TRUE,1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much, it help me=)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Conditional Formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).  Specifically Example 2 under the *Use advanced conditional formatting* topic.  I believe the checkbox will have a value of true when checked.

Comment: Thank you very much, it help me=)